# How to make a csv from json with variable array lengths using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a JSON with the following format

```
{
    "type": "conversation",
    "id": "1234",
    "created_at": 1425586662,
    "initial_message": {
        "type": "initial_message",
        "id": "567",
        "body": "<p>Testing</p>",
        "author": {
            "type": "admin",
            "id": "9382"
        }
    },
    "conversation_parts": {
        "type": "conversation_part.list",
        "conversation_parts": [
            {
                "type": "conversation_part",
                "id": "6789",
                "part_type": "comment",
                "body": "<p>Good test</p>",
                "created_at": 1425586731,
                "author": {
                    "type": "user",
                    "id": "029384"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "conversation_part",
                "id": "9384",
                "part_type": "close",
                "body": null,
                "created_at": 1425929944,
                "author": {
                    "type": "admin",
                    "id": "9382"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There is always an initial_message, but there may or may not be anything in the array of conversation parts, and that array may have any number of members.

I'm trying to capture some of this information in a csv, though I've had no luck with the @csv function

I tried:

```
jq '"\(.type), \(.id), \(.created_at), \(.initial_message.type), \(.initial_message.id), \(.initial_message.author.type), \(.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[].part), \(.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[].id), \(.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[].part_type), \(.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[].created_at), \(.conversation_parts.conversation_parts[].author.type)"' \
```

but it gives me all possible combinations of things within the array (I get 32 lines of results from this one example).

I'm editing the total amount of info I'm looking for for brevities sake, but my ideal would be to display

```
1234, 567, initial, admin
1234, 6789, comment, user
1234, 9384, close, admin
```

though I would be just fine if I could make it be

```
1234, 567, admin, 6789, comment, user
1234, 567, admin, 9384, close, admin
```

what I can't have is

```
1234, 567, admin, 6789, comment, user
1234, 567, admin, 9384, comment, admin
1234, 567, admin, 6789, close, user
1234, 567, admin, 9384, close, admin
```

which is what I'm getting now

I know there's a length function in jq and a foreach function, but then I get tangled up in my pipeline about how to loop through the array of conversation parts. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you have an array e.g.

```
[1,2,3]
```

then [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) and [object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) filters using `[]` array iteration will generate multiple strings or objects, e.g.

```
$ jq -Mnc '[1,2,3] | {x:.[]}'
{"x":1}
{"x":2}
{"x":3}

$ jq -Mnc '[1,2,3] | "x:\(.[])"'
"x:1"
"x:2"
"x:3"
```

if multiple `[]` are present then a cartesian product of combinations will be produced.  e.g.

```
$ jq -Mnc '[1,2,3] | "x:\(.[]) x:\(.[])"'
"x:1 x:1"
"x:2 x:1"
"x:3 x:1"
"x:1 x:2"
"x:2 x:2"
"x:3 x:2"
"x:1 x:3"
"x:2 x:3"
"x:3 x:3"
```

if this is not what you want, an easy way to avoid it is to move the `[]` out of the interpolation, e.g

```
$ jq -Mnc '[1,2,3] | .[] | "x:\(.) x:\(.)"'
"x:1 x:1"
"x:2 x:2"
"x:3 x:3"
```

Also, [variable binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...) is often helpful when working with a nested structure.  e.g.

```
$ jq -Mnc '{a:100, b:[1,2,3]} | .a as $a | .b[] | "a:\($a) b:\(.)"'
"a:100 b:1"
"a:100 b:2"
"a:100 b:3"
```

Finally, here a filter which uses these features to solve this problem.  [Functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DefiningFunctions) are used to keep the logic dealing with the initial message and conversation parts separate.

```
def initial:
    .id as $id
  | .initial_message
  |   .type as $ity
  |   .id   as $iid
  |   .author
  |     .type as $iaty
  |     "\($id), \($iid), \($ity), \($iaty)"
;

def parts:
    .id as $id
  | .conversation_parts.conversation_parts[]  # note [] here
  |   .id as $cid
  |   .part_type as $cpt
  |   .author
  |     .type as $caty
  |     "\($id), \($cid), \($cpt), \($caty)"
;

  initial
, parts
```

If `filter.jq` contains this filter and `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
$ jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

will produce

```
1234, 567, initial_message, admin
1234, 6789, comment, user
1234, 9384, close, admin
```